# How can I download WWDC 2013 videos straight to my iPad?

Tags: itunes, ios, ipad

I want to download some WWDC session videos to my iPad. I don't want to download them to iTunes, then transfer them to my iPad. Is there a way to download them directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official [Apple Developer](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-developer/id640199958) app is available for iPadOS and supports downloading videos.

> • Watch videos from current and past events and download them to watch offline.

Answer (score 1):

**WWDC13** videos *cannot be downloaded or watched* on official Apple websites such as [Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/) where the latest available WWDC video playlist is WWDC14.

---

Nevertheless, below is how to download WWDC videos (from WWDC14 until now).

Here are the links to every WWDC video playlist from WWDC14 (oldest available on on [Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/)) until now:

- [WWDC23](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2023/) (lasting from June 5th to June 9th 2023)
- [WWDC22](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2022/)
- [WWDC21](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2021/)
- [WWDC20](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2020/)
- [WWDC19](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2019/)
- [WWDC18](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2018/)
- [WWDC17](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2017/)
- [WWDC16](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2016/)
- [WWDC15](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2015/)
- [WWDC14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2014/)

The videos available on [Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/) (including WWDC14 and later videos) are of course available for download on iPad.

---

The below example is with a WWDC23 video: [Platforms State of the Union](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/102/).

Below the video description, in *Resources*, you can download the full video in HD or SD. (It applies for every video available on [Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/))

[image: Screenshot taken on iPad of an Apple Developers video page https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/102/ with HD and SD download buttons made more visible]

<sub>*(Download [HD](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2023/102/2/FFB36685-F7E8-4810-8814-EBD5DCBE3610/downloads/wwdc2023-102_hd.mp4?dl=1) or [SD](https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2023/102/2/FFB36685-F7E8-4810-8814-EBD5DCBE3610/downloads/wwdc2023-102_sd.mp4?dl=1) (download links) videos of the above-linked WWDC23 video)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Not really a way to how to download them directly. In order to get in touch with your iPod, iPhone and iPad using a computer is actually iTunes since iTunes will sync the iOS Software.

This might help : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4030410?start=30&tstart=0

And some more here : http://www.copytrans.net/support/install-apps-to-iphone-ipad-and-ipod-touch-without-itunes/

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-sync-music-to-your-iphone-without-itunes/